# Remove TinyMCE style

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Using TinyMCE's `setStyle` (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.setStyle), I could set the style of an element such as:

```
<img style="border-width: 3px; border-style: solid;" id="avatar" width="40" height="40" alt="avatar.png" src="avatar.png" >

tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle('avatar', 'border-width', '2px');
```

How can I remove a style?  For instance, I wish to remove `border-width` and `border-style`?  I recognize I could just set `border-width` to zero, however, do not wish to as it creates other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE doesn't appear to have any method to do so. Instead, use `style`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/vcvj22rj/2/

```
<input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" id="remove" />
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%">
        <div id="myDiv" style="background-color: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px"></div>
    </textarea>
</form>

tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
});


$('#add').click(function () {
    //Question?  Is it "better" to use the ID or select the actual element?
    //var div=tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('div');
    //tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setStyle(div, 'border-width', '5px');
    //tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setStyle(div, 'border-style', 'solid');
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setStyle("myDiv", 'border-width', '5px');
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.setStyle("myDiv", 'border-style', 'solid');
});

$('#remove').click(function () {
    var div=tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('div')[0];
    console.log(div,div.style);
    //Where is "style" property documented?
    div.style.removeProperty("border-width");
    div.style.removeProperty("border-style");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the docs, there is no "removeStyle"-like option .

Maybe you could set the value to inherit?

Comment: Yes, I looked as well and didn't see anything.  How would inherit work?

Comment: Setting the value to "inherit" would make all values inherited from their parent's element calculated value. So it would not interrupt with order styles in your style-sheet. So they're not actually removed, but the net effect is zero